# Show the rate of change of distance between two cyclists is independent of time.

Tags: calculus

I just want to check that I'm on the right tracks. The problem is:

[image]

I've drawn a diagram, a right angled triangle with xt labelled on the horizontal edge, yt on the vertical and $\sqrt{(xt)^2+(yt)^2}$ on the hypotenuse.

I've noted that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=4/3$ from $\dfrac{dy}{dt}\times \dfrac{dt}{dx}$

How should I proceed? Am I on the right lines? Do I need to take the derivative of $\sqrt{(xt)^2+(yt)^2}$ and somehow show there are no t terms?

Comment: it depends on what rate of change of distance between two cyclists means in this context (its not clear), but your approach seems fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not really helpful -- your idea of differentiating $\sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}$ with respect to $t$ holds more promise.

Before you start differentiating, though, it will help to insert $x(t)=15t$ and $y(t)=20t$ and simplifying a bit first. The actual differentiation is then very simple.

---

Note that strictly speaking it is **not true** that the rate of change is independent of time -- before they cyclists reach the intersection their mutual distance *decreases*; afterwards it *increases*. But the problem probably only considers the time *after* they meet.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_N(h)=20h$ be the distance the north cyclist has travelled, and $F_W(h)=15h$ the distance the west cyclist has travelled. The two cyclists are $25h$ kilometres about after $h$ hours. The rate of change $dD/dh=25$, which is a constant.